# Script to update firewall rules in aviatrix

Tags: python, bash, shell, firewall

Hi I'm trying to write a script that will automate updating firewall rules in aviatrix via apicall. currently I run curl from my admin server to achieve the goal

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://{{controller_hostname}}/v1/api' \
--form 'action=update_stateful_firewall_rules' \
--form 'CID={{CID}}' \
--form 'gateway_name=my-gw' \
--form 'rules=[
    {  
       "s_ip": "1.1.1.1/32",
       "d_ip": "2.2.2.2/32",
       "protocol": "icmp",
       "port": "",
       "deny_allow": "deny",
       "log_enable": "off"
    },
]
'
```

So far i got this

```
import requests as req

URL = 'https://23.20.97.236/v1/api'

payload = {
          'action':'list_gateway_security_policy_rules',
          'CID':'',
          'gateway_name':'egress-citadelvpc-prod',
          
}

response = req.get(url=URL, data=payload, verify=false)

print (response.json())
```

The catch is the source remains the same but the destination changes so it needs to be updated. The output should be  `please enter d_ip:` when i run the script and after entering the destination it will update it for me stating `The rule has been added`

Please help me produce this script!!

Comment: on https://curl.trillworks.com/ you can convert `curl` to Python's `requests`. And then you can run it in loop with `d_ip = input("please enter d_ip: ")` and use `d_ip` in `requests`

Comment: @furas Hi Thanks for your input. so far i got this

import requests

url = 'https://xx.xx.xxx/v1/api'
myobj = {'action':'update_stateful_firewall_rules' , 'CID':'test' , 'gateway_name':'egress-citadelvpc-prod' , 'rules': '[{"s_ip": "1.1.1.1", "d_ip": "2.2.2.2", "protocol": "tcp", "port": "7100", "deny_allow": "deny", "log_enable": "off"}]' }


x = requests.post(url, data = myobj)


am i in right direction? If I'm then would you please give me a bit more hints about loop? sorry i'm new in programming

Comment: you could add this code to question - it will be more readable. And more people will see it so maybe someone else will have some idea for you.

Comment: run it and see what you get in `x` - it is the best method to check if code is OK. I'm only not sure if `'[{"s_ip":...}]'` needs external `' '`

Comment: The external single quotes are not part of the JSON, they protect it from the shell. But in Python there is no shell. But again, click the link in the first comment, it will generate code for you.

Comment: @tripleee hi Im only getting `import requests`

`response = requests.post('https://xx.xx.xx.xxx/v1/api', verify=False)` when i try to convert my curl command